# Scaling to match the size

Tags: c++, opengl, pixel, formula, rectangles

I need a formula to scale a rectangle to fit into a bigger/**wider** rectangle. I only need to worry on the small rectangle.

The given values only I have are:

Big rectangle:

1. width
2. height (I don't think this is needed)
3. point (i.e x,y)

Small rectangle:

1. width (not really read-only, but still depends)
2. height (read only)
3. **scale** (I need a formula to compute what value would this be)
4. point

Values are relative to screen pixels.

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want? And are you familiar with the `max` and `min` functions?

Comment: @Beta I'm trying to implement a `label` like in windows form because I am making my own ui. No, I don't know and also I don't know how to apply it in formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find

```
a = width1 / height1;
b = width2 / height2;

if(a>b)
{
  scale = height1 / height2;
  point.y = y; (from big rectangle)
  point.x = (width1 - width2 * scale) / 2 + x;
}
else
{
  scale = width1 / width2;
  point.x = x; (from big rectangle)
  point.y = (height1 - height2 * scale) / 2 + y;
}
```

From what I understand, this should do what you wanted.

Edit: See PureW answer for getting the scale only.

Comment: I don't want to change any properties of the big rectangle, only the small rectangle should adjust base on big rectangle's width

Comment: Thats what I did there... Your explanation was not thorough though, so the "scale" in the above segment is the multiplier you need to apply on width and height of the small rectangle to have it fit into either height or width (depending on ratios) of the big rectangle. The big rectangle is never touched...

Comment: ah, I just misunderstood your `point.x` from `x`. But I need to change only the `scale` because I already have another function that centered(adjust x,y) the small rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

```
scale = min(big.width/small.width, big.height/small.height)
```

That should give you the largest `scale` that still fits the small rectangle inside the big one.

Comment: +1 for just fit into my simple question. Didn't imagine how simple it is. But Anton Roth's answer has more effort =P